# GA conversion from Universal to GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have to integrate GA4 integration and previously I was using Universal analytics and I already added Tag manager script in head of the section and made a significant changes regarding GA4 config in tag manager, but what I want to know what else change do I need to implement in the code to integrate GA4

I already change GA() tags to gtag(), is that worth to change it or not?